# How to extend Spring Boot's DataSourceAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to be able to leverage the Spring Boot datasource auto-configuration. However it doesn't support all the features I'm using, `logValidationErrors` in particular.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://111.11.11.11/DataBaseName
    username: someuser
    password: somepass
    testOnBorrow: true
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: select /* validationQuery */ 1 from dual
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1000    
    validationInterval: 30000
```

These aren't currently used:

```
    logValidationErrors: true
    maxAge: 1800000 # //30 Minute idle age
    removeAbondoned: true
```

Can I just grab the created DataSource bean and set those values manually? Or is there a better way to extend or wrap the autoconfiguration?

See here for more about `logValidationErrors`, etc: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with a `BeanPostProcessor`, similar to Dave Syer's suggestion:

```
@Override public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) bean;
        ds.setLogValidationErrors(true);
        ds.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        ds.setMaxAge(1800000);
    }
    return bean;
}
```

I'll also likely submit a PR to get the properties added to Spring Boot itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can fix this issue.

First, you may want to submit a pull request for `TomcatDataSourceConfiguration` against [the spring boot project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot). Adding those dependencies is straightforward (look at validationInterval [in the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/TomcatDataSourceConfiguration.java) for an example.

Or, you could create your own datasource the way you want. If a `DataSource` bean is present, boot will not attempt to create its own. Then you could just extend from `TomcatDataSourceConfiguration` and add any property you want by overriding `dataSource`. Finally, you should import your extended class so that the bean is registered, which will disable auto-configuration for it.

If you chose that last option and that works for you, it might be worthwhile to still [report an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) for those properties if you believe they could be interesting to a wider audience.

Comment: Those are newer properties for the Tomcat datasource, I guess I'll submit the pull request and see if the changes are worth requiring the newer Tomcat datasource

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would just `@Autowire` the existing `DataSource`, downcast as necessary, and then set the extra property. It can be dangerous up do that for some beans (if they initialize themselves from their properties), but I doubt if that will be a problem here.